# Display a custom image linked to a random product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce, permalinks

In WooCommerce, I want my customers to select an image that takes them to a random product when they click on it.

**Get a random product id (array):**

```
$random_product_array = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$random_product_id    = reset($random_product_array); // Get the random product ID
```

**Display a linked button to the random product:**

```
echo '<a href= "www.mylink.com/“> <img alt= “mylink” src=https://www.mylink.com/images/promo pic.png get_permalink($random_product_id) . '" class="img  alt">' width=150” height=“70”</a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly there, you just missed the product permalink in the right location.

Here using a `WP_Query`:

```
// Get a random product (array with one value)
$random_product_id_array = get_posts( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'orderby' => 'rand', 
    'fields' => 'ids' 
) );

// Get the first value from the array (the random product ID)
$random_product_id = reset($random_product_array);

// Output
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($random_product_id).'"><img alt="mylink" src="https://www.mylink.com/images/promo-pic.png" class="img" width="150" height="70"></a>';
```

This time it works.

Or you can also use a `WC_Product_query` instead like:

```
// Get a random product (array with one value)
$random_product_id_array = wc_get_products( array(
    'limit' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'return' => 'ids'
) );

// Get the first value from the array (the random product ID)
$random_product_id = reset($random_product_array);

// Output
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($random_product_id).'"><img alt="mylink" src="https://www.mylink.com/images/promo-pic.png" class="img" width="150" height="70"></a>';
```

works the same way too.

---

**Addition:** You can embed that code in a shortcode like *(using a `WC_Product_query`):*

```
add_shortcode('random_img_link', 'display_random_img_link');
function display_random_img_link() {
    // Get a random product (array with one value)
    $query = wc_get_products( array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'return' => 'ids'
    ) );
    
    // Here define your image link
    $image_src = 'https://www.mylink.com/images/promo-pic.png';

ob_start(); // Start buffering

echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(reset($query)).'"><img alt="mylink" src="'.$image_src.'" class="img" width="150" height="70"></a>';

return ob_get_clean(); // return  buffered content
}
```

Or *(using a `WP_Query`)*:

```
add_shortcode('random_img_link', 'display_random_img_link');
function display_random_img_link() {
    // Get a random product (array with one value)
    $query = get_posts( array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'orderby' => 'rand', 
        'fields' => 'ids' 
    ) );
    
    // Here define your image link
    $image_src = 'https://www.mylink.com/images/promo-pic.png';

ob_start(); // Start buffering

echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(reset($query)).'"><img alt="mylink" src="'.$image_src.'" class="img" width="150" height="70"></a>';

return ob_get_clean(); // return  buffered content
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:** `[random_img_link]`

Comment: it doesnt seem to load a new product, am i doing something wrong

Comment: @mosley92 yes strange… I have updated my answer code… This time it works.

Comment: it works. thanks. I think it could have been an issue with my application of this for the original code